# How to disable GPU with TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

Using tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0rc0. I want to choose whether it uses the GPU or the CPU.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I've seen some suggestions elsewhere, but they are old and do not apply very well to newer TF versions. What worked for me was this:

```py
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
```

When that variable is defined and equal to -1, TF uses the CPU even when a CUDA GPU is available.

Comment: I actually find it more convenient to set the environmental variable from outside the script. Sometimes I might forget it in a script and when I import something from that script it automatically runs it and I have no GPU.

Comment: At 2.1 (or possibly before) up to nightly, set that environment variable to an empty string to disable GPUs

Comment: Thanks you so much for this!

Comment: TensorFlow still uses GPU even after adding this snippet. I spotted it by running `nvidia-smi` command from the terminal. The corresponding `Python` runtime was still consuming graphics memory and the GPU fans turned ON when I executed my code.

Comment: After a long fight with "Failed to get device attribute 13 for device 0" error at the computer with weak graphic card, it fixed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @hafiz031 do you have a better way to disable tf from using the gpu?

Comment: @IntegrateThis does it help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544603/tensorflow-how-do-you-monitor-gpu-performance-during-model-training-in-real-tim

Comment: Correcting my previous comment: "..The corresponding Python runtime was still consuming graphics memory and the GPU fans turned ON when I executed my code" - alright! I recently found this inconsistent behavior doesn't show up always.

Comment: When I try this, my GPU use goes down a little but it uses no GPU memory. In small keras jobs my overall speed actually goes up (I assume GPU memory is not used).

Comment: @RobertLugg On tensoflow-gpu version 2.6.0 (windows), setting to an empty string still used the GPU, but setting it to -1 disabled them from being used. I don't know why it is inconsistent between versions.

Comment: Make sure to run this *before* importing tensorflow. If you run this afterwards, it will use GPU even if this variable is set.

Answer (score 16):

For TF2:

```
try:
    # Disable all GPUS
    tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')
    visible_devices = tf.config.get_visible_devices()
    for device in visible_devices:
        assert device.device_type != 'GPU'
except:
    # Invalid device or cannot modify virtual devices once initialized.
    pass
```

Comment: RuntimeError: "Visible devices cannot be modified after being initialized"

Comment: @rjurney make sure you call this code before any tensorflow op

Comment: This is the only way that looks to work with AMD / ROCm GPUs. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I find setting the variable outside the script easiest and something that always works.

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=''
```

Run this on the command line before running your python script.